# i want to search and change array value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm new in react

I try to search and change value like this.

```
ny: "76"  ->  ny: "apple"
ny: "12"  ->  ny: "banana"
```

How can I do this?

I tried like this.

```js
const source = [{
        nx: "98",
        ny: "76",
        category: "WSD",
        fcstDate: "20210625",
        fcstTime: "1500",
        fcstValue: "2.9",
    },
    {
        nx: "98",
        ny: "12",
        category: "S06",
        fcstDate: "20210625",
        fcstTime: "1200",
        fcstValue: "0",
    },
]

const newArray = source
.filter(({ny}) => ny === "76")
.forEach((source) => (source.ny = "apple"));
```

Source

```
const source = [
  {
    nx: "98",
    ny: "apple",
    category: "WSD",
    fcstDate: "20210625",
    fcstTime: "1500",
    fcstValue: "2.9",
  },
  {
    nx: "98",
    ny: "banana",
    category: "S06",
    fcstDate: "20210625",
    fcstTime: "1200",
    fcstValue: "0",
  },
]
```

Comment: Are you wanting to search for and update a single value? multiple specific values? What have you tried on your own already? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: multiple specific values

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for anything you've tried? Even if it isn't working, that's ok.

Comment: okay! i edit the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

> ```
> const newArray = source
>   .filter(({ny}) => ny === "76")
>   .forEach((source) => (source.ny = "apple"));
> ```

This would first filter the source array for elements that have a `ny` property equal specifically to "76", and then the forEach mutates the element. This overall won't even work for a single value because forEach is a void return.

## Solution

As far as I can tell, you probably don't want to filter the source array, this removes elements from the result.

This is just one possible solution.

Create a map of the `ny` keys you want to convert to fruits, then iterate over the source array and check if there is a `ny` key/value in the map and if there is, return a shallow copy of the current element with updated `ny` property.

```
const convertMap = {
  76: "apple",
  12: "banana",
};

const res = source.map(el => {
  if (convertMap[el.ny]) {
    return {
      ...el,
      ny: convertMap[el.ny],
    };
  }
  return el;
});
```

```js
const convertMap = {
  76: "apple",
  12: "banana",
};

const source = [
  {
    nx: "98",
    ny: "76",
    category: "WSD",
    fcstDate: "20210625",
    fcstTime: "1500",
    fcstValue: "2.9",
  },
  {
    nx: "98",
    ny: "12",
    category: "S06",
    fcstDate: "20210625",
    fcstTime: "1200",
    fcstValue: "0",
  },
];

const res = source.map(el => {
  if (convertMap[el.ny]) {
    return {
      ...el,
      ny: convertMap[el.ny],
    };
  }
  return el;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: im not english speaker so my english is quite wired, but i really thx you so much!!!!!

Comment: ok thx! i got this message, "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." if i get 15 reputation, i will be back this page and vote for you. thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution...

```
  const arr = source.map(el => {
  return {...el, ny: el['ny'] === '76' ? 'Apple' : el['ny']}
  })
  console.log('arr', arr);
```

We will simply traverse our array and return the object with the new value being set for our search key. And rest map will take care. I hope this helps.